# Error of applied gift cart on local PWA setup

Tags: progressive-web-apps, graphql-js, magento2.4, pwa-studio, venia

My local setup of venia-ui pwa is throwing an error :

**Cannot query field "applied_gift_cards" on type "Cart".**

The same setup without any difference in the code is working when the code is pushed onto the server , the error justify itself as there is something wrong in the graphql Query.

But the query itself is working fine independently.

Can anyone please suggest any help for the same.

I've Tried changing the graphql queries and validating the data coming from cart, But when i use

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

import { GiftCardFragment } from '/GiftCards/giftCardFragments.gql';
import { ProductListingFragment } from '@magento/peregrine/lib/talons/CartPage/ProductListing/productListingFragments.gql';
import { PriceSummaryFragment } from '@magento/peregrine/lib/talons/CartPage/PriceSummary/priceSummaryFragments.gql';
import { AppliedCouponsFragment } from '@magento/peregrine/lib/talons/CartPage/PriceAdjustments/CouponCode/couponCodeFragments.gql';

export const CartPageFragment = gql`
    fragment CartPageFragment on Cart {
        id
        total_quantity
        ...AppliedCouponsFragment
        ...GiftCardFragment
        ...ProductListingFragment
        ...PriceSummaryFragment
    }
    ${AppliedCouponsFragment}
    ${GiftCardFragment}
    ${ProductListingFragment}
    ${PriceSummaryFragment}
`;
```

Then it returns the data as undefined, But after removing the fragments of

```
${AppliedCouponsFragment}
${GiftCardFragment}
${PriceSummaryFragment}
```

These three the page return the data, but then it throws a error on performing actions on the cart

**Cannot query field "applied_gift_cards" on type "Cart".**

the code of the three fragments are :

```
        id
        applied_coupons {
            code
        }
    }
```

```
fragment GiftCardFragment on Cart {
        __typename
        id
    }
```

```
fragment PriceSummaryFragment on Cart {
        id
        # eslint-disable-next-line @graphql-eslint/require-id-when-available
        items {
            uid
            quantity
        }
        ...ShippingSummaryFragment
        prices {
            ...TaxSummaryFragment
            ...DiscountSummaryFragment
            ...GrandTotalFragment
            subtotal_excluding_tax {
                currency
                value
            }
            subtotal_including_tax {
                currency
                value
            }
        }
        ...GiftCardSummaryFragment
        ...GiftOptionsSummaryFragment
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've Found the answer to this issue. It was related to the version of the PWA application installed.

Earlier I'd installed the PWA with AC (Adobe) configurations, but my magento2 backend was a Community edition; that’s why the conflict of the Gift card module happened.